# Delay to return the prompt control after executing "external" commands

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line, powershell, cmd.exe

I'm having some trouble to fix a strange behavior on my Machine.

**Problem**

Every time I run some "external" (not native) command on the window prompt there is some kind of a delay until the control is returned to me.

Command itself is executed normally and its output is promptly displayed. However, the cursor remains blinking for 2~5 seconds until the control is given back to me and I can execute new commands.

[image]

between the command output and get the

While working with GIT, I noticed some delay on every command and I run in the command prompt.

**Observations**

- It is affecting all kind of shells: Cmd, Powershell, Cygwin, GitBash
- It happens even with simple commands such as `git status` in a empty directory, `git --version` or `java -version`.
- It does not happens if I start windows in SAFE MODE
- Issue happens even when the Antivirus (Symantec) is disabled.

**Process Monitor**

I installed the Process Monitor and this is the output

```
16:37:09,5998830    git.exe 64492   Thread Exit
16:37:09,5999292    git.exe 64492   Thread Exit
16:37:09,5999680    git.exe 64492   Thread Exit
16:37:09,6000019    git.exe 64492   Thread Exit
16:37:11,6676766    git.exe 64492   RegOpenKey  HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\GRE_Initialize
16:37:11,6676991    git.exe 64492   RegQueryValue   HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\GRE_Initialize\DisableMetaFiles
16:37:11,6677136    git.exe 64492   RegCloseKey HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\GRE_Initialize
16:37:11,6678039    git.exe 64492   RegCloseKey HKCU\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft
16:37:11,6678144    git.exe 64492   RegCloseKey HKCU\Software\Classes\Local Settings
16:37:11,6678268    git.exe 64492   RegCloseKey HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Ole
16:37:11,6678412    git.exe 64492   RegCloseKey HKLM
16:37:11,6680708    git.exe 64492   Thread Exit
16:37:11,6700179    git.exe 64492   Process Exit
```

On that log I can see a 2 seconds delay between the `Thread Exit` and the `RegCloseKey`. So, I guess the issue is around here... Something is inducing that delay between the Thread Exit and the Process Exit. This is also the same behavior when I run `java -version`.

Does anyone have any idea about what is happening or how I can fix this issue?

Comment: If you want to avoid performing a Clean ReInstallation Procedure, @W0rmH0le, and if you are a fan of _Symantec_'s (formerly NORTON_Peter's) Static Software Utilities, then you might give it a try and run their [_Norton Utilities_](https://us.norton.com/norton-utilities). Defragmenting the _Microsoft_ _Windows_ _Registry_ DataBase might have a certain impact on that Two Seconds Delay that you are noticing. Anyway, just run them and see what output they are producing.

Comment: Try to disable the antivirus and firewall to check.

Comment: I also experience the same issue. Can confirm it is related to reading GRE_Initialize registry. Was ther eany solution for it? More exactly this is the operation which is done after long delay

Answer (score 0):

#### Does anyone have any idea about what is happening or how I can fix this issue?

Turning off processing of GDI metafiles is done by modifying the registry entry `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\GRE_Initialize\DisableMetaFiles`.

Setting `DisableMetaFiles` to `1` was advised a long while ago (2008) when there was a kernel vulnerability.

[If successfully exploited, an attacker could execute code of choice to elevate privilege on the affected system.](https://www.trendmicro.com/vinfo/us/threat-encyclopedia/archive/security-advisories/(ms09-006)%20vulnerabilities%20in%20windows%20kernel%20could%20allow%20remote%20code%20execution%20(958690))

> Turning off processing of metafiles may cause the appearance of
>   software or of system components to decrease in quality. Turning off
>   processing of metafiles may also cause the software or the system
>   components to fail completely. Examples include the following:
>
> - You cannot print on the computer.
> - Some applications on the computer may be unable to display clip art.
> - Some scenarios that involve OLE rendering may break. In particular, this problem occurs when the object server is not active.
>
> Important This is intended only as an emergency measure if the latest
>   GDI security update cannot be deployed quickly enough during an active
>   attack. Turning off all processing of metafiles has not been fully
>   tested. You should change this setting back to zero (0) as soon as
>   possible and install the latest GDI security update to help increase
>   security and to regain full functionality.

Source [A registry entry is available to turn off processing of metafiles](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/941835/a-registry-entry-is-available-to-turn-off-processing-of-metafiles)

Of course this vulnerability was subsequently patched, but as this key is being read at the exit of every command line program on your system it could be that something has been installed that hooks into your system checking if that value is still set to `1`.

Notes:

1. This key does not exist on my Windows 7 machine.
2. I cannot think of any reason why `git` should be fiddling with these registry entries.
3. [Some viruses have been known to read this particular key](https://globalsecuresolutions.com/detailed-threat-analysis-of-shamoon-2-0-malware/) ...

You could try removing this key (making sure your have adequate backups first of course)